# Deduce magnetic field based on electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I'm learning Maxwell's electromagnetic equations and i can't wrap my head around this problem:

Given the volume $x\in [0,1],  y\in [0,1], z\in [0,1]$, electric field $\vec E(x,y,z,t)$ and material constants $\epsilon, \sigma, \mu$ how can i find the magnetic field $\vec B(x,y,z,t)$ knowing that $\vec B(x,y,x,0)= \vec 0$?

Comment: Does it not look like an initial value problem for $\vec{B}$? Now, take a closer look on Faraday's law of induction in differential form.

Comment: how do i integrate $\nabla \times \vec E dt$

Comment: $\vec{E}$ is given. Therefore, you can calculate $\nabla\times\vec{E}$ explicitly. This field can be integrated over time for each point $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: You changed $\vec{B}(x,y,z,0)$ back into $\vec{B}(x,y,x,0)$. Does that mean that the B-field is only given in the diagonal plane section $\{(x,y,x)\mid x\in[0,1]\wedge y\in[0,1]\}$? That makes it a bit more interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is. It might be my professor's mistake, i can't be sure.